# how to restart java/flash from command line?

Tags: flash, java

The java/flash plugin support in the browsers seems a little iffy (not to mention hard to configure.)  My specific question is, is it possible to kill the flash/java PID and restart the process? Anyone know how to ID these plugin processes? I've closed out the browser and reopened, it doesn't seem to die with them. Is flash persistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash typically isn't persistent but can hang. For Chrome and Firefox (at least) the Flash plugin runs under the following guise (If you're using `flashplayer-nonfree`):

`/usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer.bin --plugin /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so --connection /org/wrapper/NSPlugins/libflashplayer.so/30310-2`

To find the pid you could simply run the following from the command line:

`ps -aef | grep flashplayer`

This should produce an eight columned list. The second and third columns are the pid and parent pid (respectively) so you should be able to just run `kill <pid>` replacing the bracketed pid with the numerical PID.

As for restarting the flashplayer plugin it should automatically start up again on the next invocation (or refresh) of a page requiring flash.

Comment: This has changed in the latest release to `/usr/lib/firefox-3.6.10/plugin-container` but the `ps` command stands.

Comment: When I try this the `pid` increments (by 2) on each `ps -aef` query, and isn't found when I try to kill it... Its parent pid persists though

Answer (score 1):

I generally get rid of poorly behaved flash processes with 'killall npviewer.bin'. It will usually reload with a refresh.